# Consulta múltiple en MySql

Tags: mysql

llevo días intentando crear esta consulta pero no doy con la solución, el tema es que tengo que realizar una consulta a la tabla clientes pero quiero que en la misma consulta aparezcan resultados de otras tablas, entre ellos dos COUNT para saber el número de accesos de un cliente y los pedidos realizados a través de la ID de cliente.

Dejo el query al que he llegado, pero me da el mismo número de accesos que de pedidos, lo cual es erróneo. Los demás datos los devuelve de forma correcta.

```sql
SELECT clientes.id, clientes.nombre, clientes_grupos.nombre as nombre_grupo, paises.nombre_es as nombre_pais, COUNT(clientes_accesos.id) as accesos, COUNT(pedidos.id) AS total_pedidos
 FROM clientes
 LEFT JOIN clientes_grupos on clientes_grupos.id=clientes.id_grupo
 LEFT JOIN paises on paises.id=clientes.pais
 LEFT JOIN clientes_accesos on clientes.id=clientes_accesos.id_cliente
 LEFT JOIN pedidos ON pedidos.cliente_id = clientes.id
 GROUP BY clientes.id
```

Comment: Puedes hacer un (select count(*) from clientes_accesos where id = clientes.id) as accesos en vez de  COUNT(clientes_accesos.id) as accesos ???

Comment: Claro, pero el tema es integrarlo en esa consulta, con las demás. El 'from' debe ser sobre la tabla clientes.

Comment: si, digo de ponerla dentro de la consulta que has puesto pero sustituyendo lo que tenías tu por lo que he puesto yo.

Comment: Perdona, no te entiendo, si cambio la consulta como tu dices solo me saldrá ese resultado, y necesito todos los demás en un mismo query.

Comment: Esto te digo yo: SELECT clientes.id, clientes.nombre, clientes_grupos.nombre as nombre_grupo, paises.nombre_es as nombre_pais,  (select count(*) from clientes_accesos where id = clientes.id) as accesos, COUNT(pedidos.id) AS total_pedidos
 FROM clientes ...

Comment: Perfecto!! Funciona super bien, gracias!!